# python - adding a counter in a for loop

Tags: python

My aim is to print the next 20 leap years.

Nothing fancy so far.

My question is :

> how to replace the `while` with a `for`

```
def loop_year(year):
    x = 0
    while x < 20:
        if year % 4 != 0 and year % 400 != 0:
            year +=1
            ##print("%s is a common year") %(year)
        elif year % 100 != 0:
            year +=1
            print("%s is a leap year") % (year)
            x += 1


loop_year(2020)
```

Comment: why on earth aren't you just printing `i` in your `for` loop?

Comment: What is `range(1,x = 21)` supposed to do?

Comment: Tell us more about your original problem. This is wrong regardless of what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @ReutSharabani thanks for your comment. Please find my update above

Comment: Hi @MarcusMüller indeed. I've amended my question. Sorry for the mess

Comment: You don't need to replace that loop. A `while` is the correct tool here.

Comment: @ArtOfCode I asked my question out of curiosity. Is there no other way to do that than the `while`?

Comment: @AndyK Not easily. You probably *could* replace it, but it wouldn't be good, concise, efficient, maintainable, or semantically correct.

Comment: That's what I needed to hear @ArtOfCode. Cheers mate. Points are yours, sir.

Comment: I'd like to reopen my question. I'd removed the part that was unclear, leaving only the part that matters. My question is an interesting one because I could not find the answer on the net. A lot of people are using the `while` as the only possible way. I wanted to know if I can do it with a `for`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for i in range(20):
    print(i)
```

It's that easy - `i` *is* the counter, and the `range` function call defines the set of values it can have.

---

On your update:

You don't *need* to replace that loop. A `while` loop is the correct tool - you don't want to enumerate all values of `x` from 0-20 (as a `for` loop would do), you want to execute a block of code *while* x < 20.

Answer (score 8):

If what you're asking about is having an index while iterating over a collection, that's what `enumerate` is for.

Rather than do:

```
index = -1
for element in collection:
    index += 1
    print("{element} is the {n}th element of collection", element=element, n=index)
```

You can just write:

```
for index, element in enumerate(collection):
    print("{element} is the {n}th element of collection", element=element, n=index)
```

**edit**

Responding to the original question, are you asking for something like this?

```
from itertools import count

def loop_year(year):
    leap_year_count = 0
    for year in count(year):
        if (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0):
            leap_year_count += 1
            print("%s is a leap year") % (year)
        if leap_year_count == 20:
            break

loop_year(2020)
```

That said, I agree with ArtOfCode that a `while`-loop seems like the better tool for this particular job.

Comment: Hi @magni, sorry the for my mess. Can you have a look at my updated question, please? Thanks

Comment: you are magician. Spot on. I wish to have given you the points earlier but well, what has been given is given. Next time. Thanks again.